# Tweak equation to "add" fixed points

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, curves

I hope someone can at least point me in a right direction.

I managed to close in on the equation required for a project, but have no idea about how to "add" certain characteristics that I need it to have. The equation is: $$y=-1/a(x-5)$$
It has two asymptotes that form a right angle at $(5,0)$ and as $a$ is increased, the graph (at least seems like) is symmetric along the $y=-x+5$ axis. All of this fits the purpose perfectly.

What it's missing though is two points that stay fixed as $a$ is varied, $(0,0)$ and $(5,5)$.

Basically I need to start from a straight line $y=x$ and "bend it" towards $(5,0)$ symmetrically by varying $a$, as if someone is pulling on it.

[image: Link to a graph because I can't embed images yet]

Answer (score 0):

An equation for a hyperbola like yours but centred at the origin is $y=-\frac{1}{ax}$.

If we shift its centre to $(c,-b)$ we get the equation $y=-b-\frac{1}{a(x-c)}$.

We want this to go through the points $(0,0)$ and $(5,5)$.
Substituting those coordinates results in the two equations
$$abc=1\\a(c-5)(b+5)=1$$

From $abc=a(c-5)(b+5)$ we find that $c=b+5$, which makes sense since this puts the centre $(c,-b)$ on the line of symmetry $y=5-x$.

Substituting this value for $c$ we get $ab(b+5)=1$, and solving this quadratic for $b$ we find that $b = -2.5 + \sqrt{2.5^2 + 1/a}$.

So the equation has become $y=-b-\frac{1}{a(x-b-5)}$ where $b = -2.5 + \sqrt{2.5^2 + 1/a}$. Not very nice, but I think it does what you want it to.

Comment: Thank you. I plugged it in the grapher and it behaves exactly like I described.

It's a beautiful solution from a technical standpoint but like you mentioned not very nice mathematically.

Is there perhaps a compromise in the middle? Passing through fixed points is a hard requirement but I could live with slight asymmetry for example.

Comment: Technically, I could just as easily use a version of a hyperbola flipped along the $y=x$ axis, so $y=-1/ax+5$ If that makes things any easier.

Comment: @BenTait Then you get $y=-b+\frac{1}{a(x+b)}$ with the same horrible expression for $b$. That equation is nicer though when written as $a(y+b)(x+b)=1$, which shows off the x,y symmetry. It's just that the value of $b$ needed to get it through the fixed points is horrible.

Comment: Another idea in the name of mathematical beauty: I could use similar formula but with any two fixed points, as long as distance from each to both axes are equal.

I can just calculate the curve conveniently like that, extract the coefficient out of it and then just arithmetically map actual values onto it.

So, the fixed points could actually be for example $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: oh, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I plugged in the "flipped" version into the grapher and it comes out flpped along the $x=2.5$ axis instead of $y=x$.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. If you want to flip it like that, I think you just use the other root of the quadratic for $b$, so put a minus sign before the square root.